# Display content if row == 1 if row ==0 do not display

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a log in script that creates a $_SESSION based on the username of the user logging in. On another page I wish to display content if the row for that user has a 1 in it. If it has a 0 in that row, then do not display the content. I am having issues here with no matter what I've tried, it does not display YES no matter the user I log in with.

test1 = 1
test2 = 0

```
<?
require_once 'dbinfo.php';

$sess = $_SESSION['authuser'];

    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));
    $acc = "SELECT username FROM admins WHERE username = '$sess'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $acc) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));
    ob_start();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
     if($row['access'] == 1)
     {
      echo 'YES';
     }
     elseif ($row['access'] == 0)
     {
        echo 'NO';
     }
    }
    ob_end_flush()
?>
```

The solution was easy and Class pointed it out. Forgot to SELECT access... instead of username. Rookie mistake.

Comment: The first thing you should do is start using parameterized queries.  The way you query now, things aren't being escaped correctly.  Next, `var_dump($result);` after your query and see what you get.  Next, `var_dump($_SESSION)`.  Are you starting your session somewhere?

Comment: `SELECT access…` You aren't fetching the `access` column

Comment: Oh geeze. I feel really dumb now. Thank you Class, I missed that. I went through several different iterations of the coding and must have missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
 session_start();
```

in all of your files that want to make use of `$_SESSION` .

And your select query will only output the username column, as you have selected only this one, try it with

```
SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '$sess'
```

or

```
SELECT username, access FROM admins WHERE username = '$sess'
```

instead.

**What you absolutely should do is learning prepared statements, as your actual query is wide open to sql injections.**

Prepared Statement example ([from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php))

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt->close();
}

    $mysqli->close();
```

[You can read more about mysqli prepared statements here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

write access (column) and Try using isset() function and the operator === when you get 0 in a  returned variable.